# automatically open an elf for user

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface

I'm using CLISH for my beaglebone

Now,

I want the CLISH ELF to open automatically when a specific user logs in, and when the user closes the ELF,the user logs out (think of a cisco switch cli functionality).

Thanks.

Comment: Having just Googled "beaglebone" and "CLISH" . . . this doesn't seem like a programming question to me. It sounds like you're just trying to do the equivalent of setting your login shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `clish` is installed in `/usr/local/bin`, the command `sudo chsh -s /usr/local/bin/clish user` changes *user*'s login shell to `clish`.